# Basic block in LLVM IR seems broken in assembly codes

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I add debug info to the first and last instruction of the basic blocks by llvm pass, and then I successfully find the info I add in the assembly codes. But the numbers of info of first instruction and last instruction are different.

I want to know if the result is correct, and if it is correct, why the numbers are different and how to correctly get the boundary of block in assembly code?

The code of my pass

```
  bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override {
    unsigned start = 2333;
    unsigned end = 23333;
    MDNode *N = F.getMetadata("dbg");
    for (BasicBlock &B : F) {
      errs() << "Hello: ";
      Instruction *I = B.getFirstNonPHI();
      DebugLoc loc = DebugLoc::get(start, 0, N);
      if (loc && I!=NULL) {
        I->setDebugLoc(loc);
      } else {
        errs() << "start error";
      }
      I = B.getTerminator();
      loc = DebugLoc::get(end, 1, N);
      if (loc && I!= NULL) {
        I->setDebugLoc(loc);
      } else {
        errs() << "end error";
      }
      errs() << "\n";
    }
    return true;
  }
};
}
```

It runs without any errors. Some of the result:

```
# %bb.2:                                # %for.body
                                        #   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    .loc    1 2333 0                # myls.c:2333:0
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
.Ltmp4:
    .loc    1 71 14                 # myls.c:71:14
    movl    %eax, -8(%ebp)
.Ltmp5:
.LBB0_3:                                # %for.cond1
                                        #   Parent Loop BB0_1 Depth=1
                                        # =>  This Inner Loop Header: Depth=2
    .loc    1 2333 0                # myls.c:2333:0
    movl    -8(%ebp), %eax
.Ltmp6:
    .loc    1 71 18                 # myls.c:71:18
    cmpl    n, %eax
.Ltmp7:
    .loc    1 23333 1               # myls.c:23333:1
    jge .LBB0_13

......

LBB2_10:                               # %sw.epilog
    .loc    1 23333 1               # myls.c:23333:1
    jmp .LBB2_11
.LBB2_11:                               # %while.cond
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    .loc    1 162 13                # myls.c:162:13
    cmpl    $0, -164(%ebp)
    .loc    1 23333 1               # myls.c:23333:1
    jl  .LBB2_20
# %bb.12:                               # %while.body
                                        #   in Loop: Header=BB2_11 Depth=1
.Ltmp75:
    .loc    1 164 14                # myls.c:164:14
    movl    -136(%ebp), %eax
    .loc    1 164 28 is_stmt 0      # myls.c:164:28
    movl    -164(%ebp), %ecx
                                        # kill: def $cl killed $ecx
    .loc    1 164 25                # myls.c:164:25
    movl    $1, %edx
    shll    %cl, %edx
    .loc    1 164 22                # myls.c:164:22
    andl    %edx, %eax
    cmpl    $0, %eax
.Ltmp76:
    .loc    1 23333 1 is_stmt 1     # myls.c:23333:1
    je  .LBB2_18
```

I find the *2333* and *23333* don't match, and the numbers of *2333* and *23333* are different in assembly code for different architectures. I use opt to run my pass and llc to get the assembly code.

I appreciate every help.

Comment: Try the `-print-after-all` option to find out when the instructions with the debug info are removed.

Comment: You might want to profile the statistics in your pass. Get count of the first instruction you instrumented, and that of the last instruction. Also, you want to make sure the first and last instructions of the basic block are not the same

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with optimization. After your pass, the IR goes through other rounds of optimization that changed the basic blocks and eliminated some instructions.

You probably have a register function like the following from [LLVM page](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html)

```
static llvm::RegisterStandardPasses Y(
    llvm::PassManagerBuilder::EP_EarlyAsPossible,
    [](const llvm::PassManagerBuilder &Builder,
       llvm::legacy::PassManagerBase &PM) { PM.add(new Hello()); });
```

Try use `EP_OptimizerLast` rather than `EP_EarlyAsPossible`. That will run your pass as the last optimizer.

The other option is to use `EP_EnabledOnOptLevel0` and use opt with `-O0`.

You can look up the flags in this [page](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1PassManagerBuilder.html)

---

It might be helpful to use `-emit-llvm` to generate LLVM IR in `*.ll`. It is more visible what your code has done to the IR